# SQL:Looping and Reading from XML type

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

i have set of records from XML type and i need to loop through the Nodes and extract data from them

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <OP xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Types.xsd">
        <ID>
          <FDSerial>00000008</FDSerial>
          <Type>1</Type>
        </ID>
        <Param>1</Param>
        <OperationName>ReadData</OperationName>
      </OP>
      <OP xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Types.xsd">
        <ID>
          <FDSerial>00000009</FDSerial>
          <Type>1</Type>
        </ID>
        <Param>1</Param>
        <OperationName>ReadData</OperationName>
      </OP>
    </Data>
```

i already read from the record but i need to loop through the Nodes

```
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://tempuri.org/Types.xsd' as ns) 
SELECT  Data.value('/Data[1]/ns:Op[1]/ns:ID[1]/ns:FDSerial[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        as Serial   
  FROM [dbo].[DB]
```

what i need to replace the # 1 with i in a loop

Update:
i updated the xml data.

the expected from this data is the Nodes value of the FDSerial.
i hope i explained my issue clearly

Comment: What is your expected output using the sample XML you have provided?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a bigger XML file with the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all. Use [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in a cross apply to shred on `/Data/OP`.

```sql
with xmlnamespaces('http://tempuri.org/Types.xsd' as ns)
select T.X.value('(ns:ID/ns:FDSerial/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Serial
from dbo.DB
  cross apply DB.Data.nodes('/Data/ns:OP') as T(X)
```

Comment: thank you for your help,actually i did it before but because of the test xml the serial was all like 00000008 so i thought it didn't work :(.

Answer (score 0):

this will work also

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://tempuri.org/Types.xsd' as ns) 
SELECT  Data.value('(Data/ns:Op/ns:ID/ns:FDSerial/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        as Serial   
  FROM [dbo].[DB]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.